Frenet-type equations for Minkowski space
I seem to be making a very silly mistake, but cannot find where.
Let $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{1}$ be the Minkowski space endowed with the inner product
$$ \langle x, y \rangle_{1} = -x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3  $$
We wish to find Frenet-type equations for this space. For this, we consider the three-frame defined as follows. Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be vectors such that $\langle e_i, e_i \rangle_{1} = \pm 1$ and $\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle_{1} = 0$, with $e_3 := e_1 \times e_2$. Let $\varepsilon, \eta \in \{1,-1\}$ such that $\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle_{1} = \varepsilon$, $\langle e_2, e_2 \rangle_{1} = \eta$. We would like to compute $\langle e_3, e_3 \rangle_{1}$. For this, we note that
$$ \langle e_3, e_3 \rangle_{1} = \langle e_1 \times e_2, e_3 \rangle_{1} = \det(e_1,e_2,e_3) = e_1 \cdot (e_2 \times e_3) $$
and
$$ e_2 \times e_3 = e_2 \times (e_1 \times e_2) = e_1(e_2 \cdot e_2) - e_2(e_2 \cdot e_1) = \eta e_1 $$
So $\langle e_3,e_3 \rangle_{1} = \varepsilon \eta$. But the book that I am using states that $\langle e_3, e_3 \rangle_{1} = -\varepsilon \eta$. I have been looking at this for a few hours and cannot find my mistake. Would appreciate any help.

How is the cross-product defined, taking the Minkowski metric into account? After all, the notion of a right-handed system is messed up, is it not?

The author has not yet introduced the MInkowski metric. He only states that "a (modified) vector product of two vectors A and B can be defined, by requiring the relation $\langle A \times B, C \rangle_{1} = \det(A,B,C)$ ". To be honest, I also do not quite understand what he is doing here.

We’re in Minkowski space. How has he not introduced the definition? Since the inner product is indefinite, there are null vectors and thus the inner product cannot define the cross-product.

@TedShifrin Minkowski having null vectors shouldn’t affect things. We have an oriented 3-dimensional vector space (here using $\det$) and a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form, so we can define the cross product the usual way via the formula above.

@TedShifrin The author simply has not introduced the Minkowski metric. He has only introduced the inner product.

I was using the terms interchangeably, sorry. So here’s my confusion, @peek-a-boo: Using that formula, what is $e_3 \times (e_1-e_2)$ with these the standard basis vectors?

@Montresor same thing. Your first line where you define $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ is what we’re calling the Minkowski metric (sure, it’s a slight abuse of language to identify tensors with the corresponding parallelly-translated tensor fields, but we’re on a vector space so it’s fine).

@TedShifrin let $m$ denote the Minkowski metric here and $\times_m$ the induced cross product (defined using $\det$) and let $\times$ be the usual cross prodcut using the Euclidean metric. Then, with ${e_1,e_2,e_3}$ being the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^3$, we have $e_1\times_me_2=e_3$ and  $e_1\times_me_3=-e_2$ and $e_2\times_me_3=-e_1$. For the usual cross product, the first two equations hold, but the last is of course $e_2\times e_3=e_1$ instead of $-e_1$. Anyway, with this, we see that $e_3\times_m(e_1-e_2)=e_2-e_1$, as opposed to $e_3\times(e_1-e_2)=e_2+e_1$.

@peek-a-boo Sorry if my question sounds dim, but I still don't quite understand why $\langle A \times B, C \rangle_{1} = \det(A,B,C)$ allows us to define a cross product. Will the BAC-CAB formula in this case be the same, but with different signs?

See Section 1.6 and Chapter 2 in my Lorentz geometry book -- it has everything you want: https://www.routledge.com/Introduction-to-Lorentz-Geometry-Curves-and-Surfaces/Couto-Lymberopoulos/p/book/9780367468644

Like the other answer says, you seem to be mixing up the Minkowski and Euclidean metrics and their associated cross products. Also, you invoked the ‘ACB-ABC’ rule for the triple product, but that’s only true for the usual Euclidean cross product. I’m sure there’s an extra minus sign in the Minkowski version.

Let me denote $m\equiv\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ and let $\times_m$ be the associated cross product. Due to non-degeneracy of $m$, we can define $\times_m:\Bbb{R}^3\times\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^3$ to be the map such that for all $\xi,\eta\in\Bbb{R}^3$, the vector $\xi\times_m\eta\in\Bbb{R}^3$ is uniquely determined by the requirement that for all $\zeta\in\Bbb{R}^3$,
\begin{align}
m(\xi\times_m\eta,\zeta)&:=\det(\xi,\eta,\zeta).\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Another way of saying this is that if we denote $m^{\flat}:\Bbb{R}^3\to (\Bbb{R}^3)^*$, $m^{\flat}(\xi):=m(\xi,\cdot)$, then this map is an isomorphism (by non-degeneracy), so the inverse map, denoted $m^{\sharp}$ can be used to define
\begin{align}
\xi\times_m\eta:=m^{\sharp}\left(\det(\xi,\eta,\cdot)\right).
\end{align}
It is easily seen that $\times_m$ is bilinear and alternating.
Next, if $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ denotes the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^3$ (not the $e_1,e_2,e_3$ you define in your post), then for every $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^3$, we can decompose it as
\begin{align}
\xi&=-m(\xi,e_1)e_1+m(\xi,e_2)e_2+m(\xi,e_3)e_3.\tag{$**$}
\end{align}
The minus sign here is because $m(e_1,e_1)=-1$ (as opposed to the Euclidean case where $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle=1$). By combining $(*)$ and $(**)$, we see that for all $\xi,\eta\in\Bbb{R}^3$,
\begin{align}
\xi\times_m\eta&=-m(\xi\times_m\eta,e_1)e_1+ m(\xi\times_m\eta,e_2)e_2 + m(\xi\times_m\eta,e_3)e_3\\
&=-\det(\xi,\eta,e_1)e_1+ \det(\xi,\eta,e_2)e_2+ \det(\xi,\eta,e_3)e_3\tag{$***$}
\end{align}
By using $(***)$, we can easily compute:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
e_1\times_me_2&=e_3\\
e_1\times_me_3&=-e_2\\
e_2\times_me_3&=-e_1.
\end{cases}
\tag{$!$}
\end{align}
By the bilinearity and alternating nature of $\times_m$, all other cross products can be computed from these three equations. Btw, you should compare this with the usual cross product, where there isn’t a minus sign in the third equation:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
e_1\times e_2&=e_3\\
e_1\times e_3&=-e_2\\
e_2\times e_3&=e_1.
\end{cases}
\tag{$!!$}
\end{align}

Anyway, the situation you have is slightly different. Let $\xi_1,\xi_2$ be $m$-orthonormal vectors, i.e
\begin{align}
m(\xi_1,\xi_1),m(\xi_2,\xi_2)\in\{-1,1\}, \quad\text{and}\quad m(\xi_1,\xi_2)=0.
\end{align}
Now, general theory tells me that the $1$-dimensional subspace which is $m$-orthogonal to $\text{span}\{\xi_1,\xi_2\}$ is not a null subspace (i.e not lightlike), i.e I can find a third vector $\xi_3$ such that
\begin{align}
m(\xi_3,\xi_3)\in\{-1,1\},\quad\text{and}\quad m(\xi_3,\xi_1)=m(\xi_3,\xi_2)=0.
\end{align}
Let me now define $\epsilon_i:=m(\xi_i,\xi_i)\in\{-1,1\}$ and set $\epsilon:=\det(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)$. Before proceeding, let us just note that due to Minkowski signature, we have $\epsilon_1\epsilon_2\epsilon_3=-1$, and $\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}$ (this is a general feature of ‘orthonormal’ bases in pseudo-inner-product spaces).
Now, the analogue of the basis expansion $(**)$ above is that for all $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^3$, we have
\begin{align}
\xi&=\epsilon_1m(\xi,\xi_1)\xi_1+\epsilon_2m(\xi,\xi_2)\xi_2+\epsilon_3m(\xi,\xi_3)\xi_3.\tag{$@$}
\end{align}
(Once again, the signs $\epsilon_i:=m(\xi_i,\xi_i)$ account for the Minkowski signature). By now applying the formula $(@)$ with the vector $\xi_1\times_m\xi_2$, we find that
\begin{align}
\xi_1\times_m\xi_2&= 
\epsilon_1m(\xi_1\times_m\xi_2,\xi_1)\xi_1
+\epsilon_2m(\xi_1\times_m\xi_2,\xi_2)\xi_2
+\epsilon_3m(\xi_1\times_m\xi_2,\xi_3)\xi_3\\
&=\epsilon_1\det(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_1)\xi_1
+\epsilon_2\det(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_2)\xi_2
+\epsilon_3\det(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)\xi_3\\
&=0+0+\epsilon_3\epsilon \cdot \xi_3.\tag{i}
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
m(\xi_1\times_m\xi_2,\xi_1\times_m\xi_2)&=(\epsilon_3\epsilon)^2m(\xi_3,\xi_3)=1\cdot \epsilon_3=-\epsilon_1\epsilon_2.\tag{ii}
\end{align}
This shows that your textbook is right. In fact, this equation can be expressed equivalently as
\begin{align}
\det(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_1\times_m\xi_2)&=-\epsilon_1\epsilon_2.\tag{iii}
\end{align}
The results of (i),(ii),(iii) can be summarized by the following theorem:

Theorem.
If $\{\xi_1,\xi_2\}$ is an $m$-orthonormal set, then $\{\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_1\times_m\xi_2\}$ is an $m$-orthonormal basis, and the orientation is determined by the causal properties of $\xi_1,\xi_2$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\det(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_1\times_m\xi_2)=-\epsilon_1\epsilon_2.
\end{align}


Slightly more generally, let $(V,g,\omega)$ be a $3$-dimensional real vector space with pseudo-inner product $g$ (with $\#$ many minus signs in its orthonormal decomposition) and volume element $\omega$ which is normalized such that $\omega$ acting on a $g$-orthonormal basis yields $\pm 1$. Let $\times_{g,\omega}:V\times V\to V$ be the cross product defined by the formula
\begin{align}
g(\xi\times_{g,\omega}\eta,\zeta):=\omega(\xi,\eta,\zeta)
\end{align}
or equivalently,
\begin{align}
\xi\times_{g,\omega}\eta:= g^{\sharp}(\omega(\xi,\eta,\cdot)),
\end{align}
where $g^{\sharp}:V^*\to V$ is the inverse musical isomorphism of $g^{\flat}:V\to V^*$, $g^{\flat}(\xi):=g(\xi,\cdot)$. With this notation out of the way, we have the following theorem:

Theorem.
If $\{\xi_1,\xi_2\}$ is $g$-orthonormal, then $\{\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_1\times_{g,\omega}\xi_2\}$ is a $g$-orthonormal basis with orientation determined by the causal properties of $\xi_1,\xi_2$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\omega(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_1\times_{g,\omega}\xi_2)=(-1)^{\#} g(\xi_1,\xi_1)g(\xi_2,\xi_2)\in\{-1,1\}.
\end{align}


Thanks a lot for your answer. It will take me a while to digest this, but I think I get the main idea now.

I think your problem is, that you are mixing the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ on your space with the euclidean inner product $\cdot$ .
This causes issues in multiple places, for example, in your last computation $\langle e_1,e_2\rangle_1=0$ does not imply $e_1\cdot e_2=0.$
It also means that, as you have indicated in your comment, that the usual cross product of vectors is not the right tool in this context. I am not sure if there is a good cross product for indefinite inner products, a quick search has led me to this answer. You could try replacing every euclidean inner product in your calculations with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ and use the cross product and the identity for iterated cross products from the linked answer and see if that gets you anywhere.

I have tried using the cross product in the given link, but unfortunately it got me nowhere. It seems that the minus sign is still missing.
